# Purity for proper varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations

Let $X$ be a proper, geometrically connected, geometrically integral variety over $\mathbf{F}_q$. There exists a finite field extension $k/\mathbf{F}_q$ of degree $d$ and an alteration $X'\to X_k$ defined over $k$, where $X'$ is smooth and projective over $k$.

For $\ell$ a prime not dividing $q$, we have an injective map
$$H^i_{ét}(X_{\overline{k}},\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_{\ell})\subset H^i_{ét}(X'_{\overline{k}},\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_{\ell})$$

such that geometric Frobenius $F$ on $H^i_{ét}(X'_{\overline{k}},\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_{\ell})$ restricts to the $d$-th power of geometric Frobenius on $H^i_{ét}(X_{\overline{k}},\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_{\ell})\simeq H^i_{ét}(X_{\overline{\mathbf{F}}_q},\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_{\ell})$.

Fix a field isomorphism $\iota: \overline{\mathbf{Q}}_{\ell}\simeq\mathbf{C}$.

By the Weil conjectures applied to $X'$, $F$ has eigenvalues $\lambda$ with complex absolute value $$|\iota(\lambda)|=q^{di/2}$$ It looks like this implies that this is also satisfied by geometric Frobenius (to the power $d$) on $H^i_{ét}(X_{\overline{\mathbf{F}}_q},\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_{\ell})$.

This also seems to imply that geometric Frobenius on $H^i_{ét}(X_{\overline{\mathbf{F}}_q},\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_{\ell})$ has eigenvalues with complex absolute value $q^{i/2}$.

This feels wrong: I would expect the eigenvalues to have complex absolute value **bounded above** by $q^{i/2}$ (resp. $q^{di/2}$). If $X$ was itself smooth then Poincaré duality would give the reverse inequality, and so purity, but without smoothness I would expect this to not be true.

> What's being missed?

(maybe an incorrect use/statement of de Jong's theorem? I guess $X'$ needs not be projective, but only open in smooth projective)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim that alteration induces an injection on cohomology is wrong, as the example of the resolution of a nodal cubic curve by $\mathbb P^1$ shows (resolutions being a special case of alterations).

The induced map from $H^1$ of the nodal cubic to $H^1$ of $\mathbb P^1$ is not an injection, because $H^1$ of $\mathbb P^1$ vanishes but $H^1$ of the nodal cubic does not.

Comment: I thought alterations were defined to be proper, generically finite and **surjective** morphisms of algebraic varieties over $k$. Surjective maps induce injective pullbacks on $\ell$-adic cohomology (eg. Kleiman, Prop. 1.2.4 in Dix Exp.), so some confusion remains.

Comment: Ah! Of course  Kleiman's Prop. only applies to surjective maps of **smooth** proper varieties.

Comment: @Matt All varieties are assumed smooth in that paper, and the proof uses Poincare duality.

Comment: Yes indeed. Confusions resolved. Thanks!